# Cloudfront returns 403 error when I call it but the using api gateway url which is attached to cloud front returns the right result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem with cloudfront.
Here is my scenario:
1) I have a beanstalk url pointing to my get service in java. So far so good and I can see the result by calling : beanstalk url/users/1

2) I added my beanstalk to api gateway as a http and again So far so good and I can see the result by calling : api gateway url/users/1

3) now I want to create a custom domain name for my api gateway so I followed the following :

[how to set custom domain for api gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-edge-optimized-custom-domain-name.html)

I followed that and now I have a cloudfront endpoint poitng to my apigateway deployed stage with a certificate. Please look at the image:

[image]

Now when I try this:

https://de90lotxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/users/1

I get :

```
Failed to load https://de90lotelw3hx.cloudfront.net/users/1: Response to 
 preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-
 Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
 'https://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had 
 HTTP status code 403.
```

Just to clarify I did check the api gateway deployed url and I did not get this error so this means that cors are enabled in apigateway. SO when I use cloudfront and certificate do I need to attach any header? any idea?

Comment: The custom domain name, that you should use to call the API is the one you have deleted: api.stg2 etc etc, de90... is "internal"ù

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the CORS headers enabled in api gateway.

Select the resource (/users/{id}), click the Actions button, and select Enable CORS from the drop down. The default settings (shown in the screen capture) is wildcard / all domains. Click the "Enable CORS.." button to confirm.

This will send the CORS headers in the response and allow the cross domain request to s.codepen.io from the web application.

Last, don't forget to deploy the stage after making changes.

[image]